# Android webview - Set token to post request

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem with a webview in my app.

I need to set a token in order to be connected automatically.

To do that, I added header for the first loading page and for each loading pages with the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method.

So here is my code :

```
final Map<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<>();
extraHeaders.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    extraHeaders.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    view.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
  }
```

}

This code works : I am automatically authenticated  for the first display and for the next pages inside the webview.

On the other side, I have a problem with a form. When I submit the form, I am redirected to the login page and, because I set the token to each page, I am redirected to the home page of the site.

**The token is not set when the submit request POST is done.**

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I think I'm hitting the same issue, but I'm coming through Xamarin, so I have another layer of abstraction in there.